# ansible format with nested loop

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have an ansible variable that I want to auto generate. I try to format a dynamic list of strings with incremental indexes and I can't seem to make this work nicely.

The result I want is something like this for a range of 3 -

```
server-01.example.com,server-02.example.com,server-03.example.com
```

So I've tried -

```
"{{ [server-%02d.example.com] | product(range(1,4))) | map('format') | join(',') }}"
```

But it looks like I can't pass `format` a variable from my nested list...

I know I have some alternatives, like using `regex_replace`, or using 2 `product` and 2 `join` to concat the string, but I don't want to lose the advantage of `%02d` and the problem doesn't look like a rare one, so anyone has an idea?

Comment: `format` needs to receive the variable to replace in the string as an argument, i.e. your `[1,2,3,4]` generated by the range.